# How to disable Tomcat remote deployment?

Tags: java, tomcat

For security reasons, I would like to disable the remote deployment of web applications via Tomcat's manager page, which allows one to upload and deploy a war file.  Is this possible?

Are there any other recommendations for hardening Tomcat against possible attacks?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the manager for anything else? Can you just not install it?

Comment: I would like to keep the manager accessible to allow me to restart web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the manager (and also the other preinstalled folders) from the tomcat/webapps folder.

Answer (score 0):

web application could be restricted by the remote IP address or host by adding a RemoteAddrValve or RemoteHostValve in context.xml

```
<Context privileged="true">
         <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
                allow="127\.0\.0\.1"/>
</Context>
```

http://blog.techstacks.com/2009/05/tomcat-management-setting-up-tomcat.html

Comment: Make sure you include the path="/manager" attribute!!! I just copied and pasted the above and it took down my website!